# How to get Array from API GET request

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, api, express

I have an API as follows

```
{
  "author": [],
  "categories": [],
  "_id": "62ff04704bcdbd99716e0cc4",
  "kind": "books",
  "items": [
    {
      "title": "Java",
      "author": [
        "John",
        "Peter"
      ],
      "publisher": "North Publishers",
      "publishedDate": "12 Sep 2021",
      "description": "Learn Java",
      "pageCount": 286,
      "printType": "PaperBack",
      "categories": [
        "Programming",
        "Java"
      ],
      "language": "English",
      "price": 1856
    }
  ]
}
```

I want to get the "Items" Array from the API using Express JS

In the routes.js i have the following code :-

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const BookSchema = require('./schema');

app.get('/books', async (req,resp)=>{
    const book = await BookSchema.find({ });
    var BookArray = book[0]
    console.log(BookArray.items)
})
```

After sending a GET request i get "Undefined" in the console but i wanted the array

For reference this is the schema.js file

```
const {Schema, default:mongoose} = require('mongoose');
const bookSchema = new Schema([{
       
       kind:String,
       title:String,
       author:[String],
       publisher:String,
       publishedDate:String,
       description:String,
       pageCount:Number,
       printType:String,
       categories:[String],
       language:String,
       price:Number,
}]);
const book = mongoose.model('book',bookSchema);
module.exports = book;
```

And this is my server.js file

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const router = require('./routes');

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/book')
app.use(express.static('static'));

app.use(router);

app.listen(5000,()=>{
    console.log("Server is running at http://127.0.0.1:5000");
})
```

How do i get the array from the API

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should also add items to the book schema. You can create nested schemas like so:

```
const ItemSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  title: String,
  author: [String],
  publisher: String,
  publishDate: String,
  description: String,
  pageCount: Number,
  printType: String,
  categories: [String],
  language: String,
  price: Number
});

const bookSchema = new Schema([{
       ...
       items: [ItemSchema],
}]);

const book = mongoose.model('book',bookSchema);
module.exports = book;
```

You can read more about it [here](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/subdocs.html)